# Sending a post in android with bad encoding

Tags: android, httprequest, parameters

I'm sending post content to a server from android.
The problem is that the data at the server arrives wrong, with encoding problems, for example "{" arrives as "%7B%".

This is the code from android:

```
 RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

    params.put("alta", "{s}");
String ruta = "http://www.something.com/receive";
client.post(ruta, params,
        new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {

            }
        }
```

The server part is just receiving this data, like:

```
$data = $this->request->data;
$data =file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not directly related to text encoding per se.

As can be seen from the [docs for `RequestParams`](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/RequestParams.html), text values are directly included in the url. As all text that is included in URLs has to be encoded to only include characters that are allowed in URLs (ASCII), text is [url encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

`AsyncHttpClient` automatically does that encoding in the background, so you receive the strings in encoded form on the php side.

In order to get the original text you sent, you can use the `rawurldecode()` or `urldecode()` function on the php side to decode the encoded string you receive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URLEncoder.encode(...) the the data part of you request.
At the server URL decode it.

You should be fine.